# insert from one table into two tables

Tags: sql, database, teradata, sql-insert

I have three tables:

- Table A has columns name, id, nationality
- Table B has a column name
- Table C has a column id

I was wondering if it is possible to extract from Table A and insert its name column into Table B and id column into Table C in one single SQL query? Not in two separate queries.

I know it is possible in Oracle.

I am using Teradata, which supports all SQL queries.

Comment: please let us know if you can do it in one query.

Comment: Can you elaborate *why* you need a single request? Maybe Teradata's *Multi-Statement Request* can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do in a single query. One table at a time only. Use a Transaction or a Stored statement to query the data and then two more queries to insert the data in each table. This does save you making the query for both inserts but you cant do an INSERT on two tables.